# Requirejs working with mutiple jQuery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, r.js

I am struggling with the requirejs optimizer and multiple versions of jQuery. This code(main.js) will work if I just load it in the browser without optimization/before the build process.

```
paths:{
    'requireLib'    : 'lib/require',
    'jquery'        : 'lib/jquery',
    'jqueryLegacy'  : window.jqueryVersion, //old IE
```

If I run the optimizer I get the following: >> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory .../assets/js/jquery.js'

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/lib/jquery-legacy.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

What i am trying to achieve is to use the old jQuery version when facing old browsers and the new one when facing modern browsers. Like how i did before requirejs, see code above^.

I have tried dynamic path values in the config file (main.js) also with this fix/workaround: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/270#issuecomment-13112859

Still no result, is there a some general way to go for this approach?

Comment: You should be declaring it as part of your dependencies in RequireJS rather than as a `<script>` tag, unless I'm misunderstanding your question. BTW since jQuery 1 and 2 have the same API, you might be better off just using 1.x for all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that is exactly my question, the way i am using it as i posted but then as a dependency in requirejs (the same result but then in requirejs), for now i am using the latest jQuery 1 in require as you suggested